# How to get Ruby support in Zend Studio?

Tags: zend-studio

Zend Studio is basically Eclipse that has been optimized for working with Zend Framework projects. Well I have a few files in my Zend Framework project that happen to be Ruby files. Zend Studio doesn't come with the ability to create/edit Ruby files with syntax highlighting. I could open in the default text editor, but there won't be any syntax highlighting. How can I add support for Ruby files in Zend Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the new version of Aptana which can be added to your current zend studio configuration as an extension. It supports ruby out of the box.

---

http://www.aptana.com/products/radrails